# AWS beanstalk docker-pool devmapper running out thin pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Hi I have a few clusters running with AWS beanstalk running docker images. My docker image size is 680MB and I verified that the Docker data volume (/dev/xvdcz) is at capacity of 12GB. I also verified that there are no dangling images / stale containers to prune. Currently it is holding 2 images (so should be roughly 1.4GB).

That said my new application deployments were consistently failing with error:

```
layer: devmapper: Thin Pool has 1805 free data blocks which is less than minimum required 2425 free data blocks. Create more free space in thin pool or use dm.min_free_space option to change behavior
```

On future investigation, I found there is a setting in `/etc/sysconfig/docker-storage` that sets the dm.baseSize to 100GB. Here's the file content:

```
DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS="--storage-driver devicemapper --storage-opt dm.thinpooldev=/dev/mapper/docker-docker--pool --storage-opt dm.use_deferred_removal=true --storage-opt dm.use_deferred_deletion=true --storage-opt dm.fs=ext4 --storage-opt dm.basesize=100G"
```

This is coming from default AWS AMI. After that I added an ebextension to increase the docker volume (/dev/xvdcz) to 120GB and things have not failed since.

My question is why do we need baseSize to be 100GB and is there a way I can reduce it down to 10GB so I don't have to attach additional storage for each box? Ideally without building custom AMIs.

Here's the new config after I updated the volume to 120GB.

```
[ec2-user ~]$ lsblk
NAME                                                                                         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1                                                                                      259:1    0     8G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1                                                                                  259:2    0     8G  0 part /
└─nvme0n1p128                                                                                259:3    0     1M  0 part
nvme1n1                                                                                      259:0    0   120G  0 disk
└─nvme1n1p1                                                                                  259:6    0   120G  0 part
  ├─docker-docker--pool_tdata                                                                253:1    0 118.6G  0 lvm
  │ └─docker-docker--pool                                                                    253:2    0 118.6G  0 lvm
  │   └─docker-259:2-394917-4a52cb647e0a91037aaf4fb64345ae55567f2d8c5ff073048981987e6dcba7b0 253:3    0   100G  0 dm   /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/4a52cb647e0a91037aaf4fb64345ae55567f2d8c5ff073048981987e6dcba7b0
  └─docker-docker--pool_tmeta                                                                253:0    0   124M  0 lvm
    └─docker-docker--pool                                                                    253:2    0 118.6G  0 lvm
      └─docker-259:2-394917-4a52cb647e0a91037aaf4fb64345ae55567f2d8c5ff073048981987e6dcba7b0 253:3    0   100G  0 dm   /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/4a52cb647e0a91037aaf4fb64345ae55567f2d8c5ff073048981987e6dcba7b0
```

Comment: I encounter the same problem as you.. Can you paste the content of your .ebextension file, please?

Comment: Same issue, I increased the size to 128 Gb but the error is still there.

Answer (score 0):

By default, EB only gives you 12GB of storage for images.

To expand it to 100GB, Create a `.ebextensions/blockdevice-xvdcz.config` file with the following contents.

```
option_settings:
  aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration:
    BlockDeviceMappings: /dev/xvdcz=:100:true:gp2
```

See the "Configuring additional storage volumes" section of https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.container.console.html#docker-volumes

> For improved performance on Amazon Linux AMI, Elastic Beanstalk
> configures two Amazon EBS storage volumes for your Docker
> environment's Amazon EC2 instances. In addition to the root volume
> provisioned for all Elastic Beanstalk environments, a second 12GB
> volume named xvdcz is provisioned for image storage on Docker
> environments.
>
> If you need more storage space or increased IOPS for Docker images,
> you can customize the image storage volume by using the
> BlockDeviceMapping configuration option in the
> aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration namespace.
>
> For example, the following configuration file increases the storage
> volume's size to 100 GB with 500 provisioned IOPS: